# How to check rows value and update an already existent column with them

Tags: python, pandas

I want to update a column (`Names`) as follows:

- if the last character of a word in `Names` ends with `a` and is not `pizza`, then assign `c`;
- if the last character of a word in `Names` ends with `o` or `i` or it is `pizza`, then assign `m`.

The column to check is

```
Names

choriocarcinoma
medulloblastoma
phenylketonuria
counterguerilla
lymphogranuloma
archipelago
braggadocio
chiaroscuro
decrescendo
violoncello
accelerando
afficionado
tachyarrhythmia
teratocarcinoma
caudillismo
cinquecento
countermemo
oligodendroglia
pleuropneumonia
pizza
```

To extract the last character I did:

```
df['Names'] = [x.strip()[-1] for x in df['Names']]
```

to check and assign the new values, I did:

```
if df['Names'] == 'a': 
   df['Names'] = 'c'
elif df['Names'] in ('o','i','pizza'):
   df['Names'] = 'm'
else: 
   df['Names'] = 'Other'
```

but it does not work. Also

```
def applyFunc(s):
    if s == 'a' and s != 'pizza':
        return 'c'
    elif s in ('o','i', 'pizza'):
        return 'm'
    return 'other'
```

does not work.

Could you tell me where the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean select by combining `str.endswith()` , `ampersand` and `|`for alternative selections. Use nested `np.where`. Caution; `np.select` always the better option

```
import numpy as np
a= (df.Names.str.endswith('a'))&(df.Names!='pizza')
b= (df.Names.str.endswith('o'))|(df.Names.str.endswith('i'))|(df.Names=='pizza')




df['N']=np.where(a, 'c', np.where(b,'m',df.Names))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, [`np.select`](http://mpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and [`Series.str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html)

```
import numpy as np
c11 = df['Names'].str.endswith('a')
c12 = df['Names'].ne('pizza')
c21 = df['Names'].str.endswith('i')
c22 = df['Names'].str.endswith('o')
c23 = ~c12

c1 = c11 & c12
c2 = c21 | c22 | c23



df['new'] = np.select((c1, c2), ('c', 'm'), default='other')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
              Names new
0   choriocarcinoma   c
1   medulloblastoma   c
2   phenylketonuria   c
3   counterguerilla   c
4   lymphogranuloma   c
5       archipelago   m
6       braggadocio   m
7       chiaroscuro   m
8       decrescendo   m
9       violoncello   m
10      accelerando   m
11      afficionado   m
12  tachyarrhythmia   c
13  teratocarcinoma   c
14      caudillismo   m
15      cinquecento   m
16      countermemo   m
17  oligodendroglia   c
18  pleuropneumonia   c
19            pizza   m
```